# Storage for household stuff

Tags: storage, renovation, new-home

My wife and I decided to renovate our kitchen and living room.   We hired a renovation company for both the kitchen and the living room but the old furniture and other appliances such as the TV and refrigerator had to be moved for making space for the renovation to take place.

We have been searching online for a couple of websites for storage solutions and came across one that would help. We are new to this but could really use some help.

Could someone help and advise us on what all to look out for when choosing the right storage space?

Comment: This is really just a matter of **what works best you   and your wife** and your space. Do research for ideas, make a list of how you want to use the space, what type of items you will be storing there and then **make decisions based on the knowledge gained**.  *We can not really answer this for you*. When it comes time to build your space  and you have **specific DIY problems** you need answers to then we can help with that.

Answer (score 5):

If this is short-term and you have the space (i.e., private driveway) and permission (you don't live in a neighborhood where a homeowner's association or similar bureaucracy has rules against such things), the best thing would be a storage container that is brought to your location. Essentially like the trailer of a big truck, but designed to be lifted up onto a truck for delivery and/or long-term storage. But for short-term storage it stays on your property. That has advantages that:

- You can load/unload at your own pace.
- If you might need access to something while stored, that is a possibility (not always a possibility with many remote storage places)
- Lower cost because you are essentially renting a container without renting a place to put it.

I won't recommend any specific companies, as they vary by location (and change over time). But Google *on-site storage container* or similar and you should find something.

Comment: Great suggestion. I might also check with the construction company before choosing a spot for the container, lest the container block some access route needed for renovation equipment/material, particularly if space is tight.